# sort in descending order from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

So I was trying to write code in PHP. My goal was to write a generic code for mysql get operations. For an instance I would like to pass the table name and from and to values to get the result back in the form of JSON like below.

```
function get($table, $from, $to) {
     $q = mysqli_query('select * from '.$table.' limit '. $from.', '.$to);
     // do some more 
     return json_encode($arr);
}
```

The above code will give the result. as expected. Now the problem I face is when I want my code to return the values depending in the descending order depending on the `auto_incrment`ed column of my table. I'm completely stuck at this point.

I used to do like this when I didn't wanted a gereric code.

`select * from tablename order by auto_inc_col limit 0,10`

I tried with google to get some answers regarding the same. But couldn't get it. As per my experience I should specify the column name which I'm unable to with the code I'm trying to write now.

Now my question is this. Is it possible to specify a column name dynamically through any of the mysql queries. If possible How? Or should I quit this generic code and start writing the code for each table seperately? Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: Is the auto_inc column always the first column in the definition?

Comment: ORDER BY 1 DESC - but note that there are security issues with your present approach. Generic stuff like this is generally to be avoided!

Comment: @Strawberry can you please give me a link or explanation about the security issues with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but wouldn't something like this help ?

```
function get($table, $from, $to) {
    $q = mysqli_query('select * from '.$table.' order by auto_inc_col DESC limit '. $from.', '.$to);
```

You could even have variables $sortCol and $sortOrder.

Comment: This is what I need. I just wanted to get all records in descending order. To get that order I need to specify the column name. But I cannot as I don't have the option to get the column name dynamically. So I have the issue in getting ordered output. As per @Strawberry's advice it works. Again he says that `there are security issues with my present approach`. Bit overloaded today. But thanks for your last sentence in your post. That might help me.